# Test progress shows 0 percent complete

Tags: kiwi-tcms

All of my test runs are showing as in the attached image - in this case all tests have passed, but I am showing 0% progress for the test run.

When I initially start the test run, the progress bar updates - but subsequently disappears.

I don't have any other issues with test data, test cases, plans, etc.

[image: test progress]

Answer (score 1):

For the record this is tracked here and we're working on this area 
https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/1326